# How to present VC modally then segue to a VC that's embedded in a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

My app flow is like this:

(1) The app launches you into a `LogInViewController` that is embedded in a `NavigationController`.

(2) Inside `LogInViewController` if `runCount < 1` I want to present a set of tutorials VCs that are not embedded in a nav stack.

(3) You can tap "skip" or after swiping through the tutorial VCs you tap an "OK" `button`, all of which segue you back to `LoginViewController`.

The problem is that when you are segued back to `LogInViewController` there's no `NavigationController`.

What's the best way to approach this?

[image]

Comment: When you say that when you segue back to `LogInViewController`, "there is no `NavigationController`", do you mean that the navigation bar on top is no longer present? 

Also, this is tangential to your question, but the typical approach to doing these first time introductions is not to have the `LogInViewController` type be the first controller, but instead have something more like a default view controller be shown when the app is opened, and segues directly to the introduction when it detects that its ran the first time.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps that is the answer then creating a splash screen type VC (with no `NavigationController` embed) prior to the `LogInViewController`.  Yes, I meant that the NavigationBar is no longer present along with the error "Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x7fe6d0452220> on <PinCheck.LogInViewController: 0x7fe6d0451c30> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple, rather than wiring up the buttons to my `LogInViewController` all I needed to do was wire them up to the `NavagationController` instead since it presents the `LogInViewController`