# How to have a back button in a VC in a navigation controller stack but segued from elsewhere?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Here is the user flow I want for my chat app:

(Basically exact same as WhatsApp, and very close to iMessage)

I have a tableVC for all existing chats inside a NavigationC. When the user clicks on the search button:

I want to have searchVC come up from bottom (it is set to present modally). If user cancels, I call dismiss(animated), which works well.

But if the user clicks on a new user to chat, I segue to chat screen using show detail, but I don't get my navigation controllers back button. How would I get it? (back to conversations not searchVC)

I don't want to embed everything in the navigationC because it doesn't really belong there. Also I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971707/how-to-present-vc-modally-then-segue-to-a-vc-thats-embedded-in-a-navigation-con) answer but that does not work since I have a chatVC I want to go to. Again exact same as WhatsApp.

In images below, you can see if I click on my conversationsVC, the back button shows, but when I click on the seachVC, it disappears.
[image]

[image]

Comment: When user wants to create a new chat, you are presenting or pushing the new controller?

Comment: @iPeter Sorry Im new to this. I don't know the difference between presenting and pushing. Its set to show detail in storyboard if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Set the storyboard segue to **show**.

Comment: The segue that you have created from ConversationsVC to SearchVC is not of type "Show" instead it is of type "Show Detail". Change it to "Show" and it will work. Go to Attributes Inspector of that segue and change it to of type "Show".

Comment: If you meant to set the two segues pointing to the chat, I tried setting them to show but it didn't work. If you mean to set the one that goes to chat to show, thats not what I want.

Comment: @ShubhamOjha, Please read my description, thats not the behavior I want for two reasons. One if I do that, my cancel becomes a back button, and won't go back modally. More importantly, if the user opens a new chat, the back button will take them to search not to conversations. Again, I want the behavior of iMessage or whatsapp if you want to see it.

Comment: Hai may I know which protocol you are using for chat application

Answer (score 0):

The navigationController only records viewControllers that is using show/push to perform and so it can provide back button. Otherwise, you have to embed another navigationController. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JptA.png)